# I want to provide a functionality to our users to printscreen and then use Ctrl+V to add image as attachment without saving image anywhere

Tags: java, image, gwt, textbox

I have a GWT app and i want to provide a functionality to users simply press printscreen and then on pressing Ctrl+V it should automatically get attached as an image like gmail,skype etc.

Comment: Oh.. Nice feature buddy.

Comment: just wondering how app will decide which application to attach with ?

Comment: whatever is there on clipboard should automatically get attached to particular location in my app where i will press Ctrl+V

Answer (score 1):

There is an event for pasting:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.ONPASTE
```

I use this but only for pasting text (user must press Ctrl+V or right-click>Paste). I guess there may be a way for you to use this.

To capture the event, I sink it to my Widget first:

```
sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE | Event.ONKEYPRESS | Event.ONKEYDOWN | Event.ONFOCUS);
```

Then, I implement onBrowserEvent(Event):

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
    case Event.ONPASTE: paste(event);
    }
}
```

Hope you can find a way to adapt this for images.

Comment: "user must user Ctrl+V" - this should probably be "user must press CTRL+V"